# Нужно чтобы главное окно PyQt5 стояло всегда в главном приоритете

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, pyside2

Необходимо, чтобы окно всегда было в главном приорете, поверх всех других окон. Другими словами, необходим аналог функции из `Tk.wm_attributes()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt::**WindowStaysOnTopHint**

Сообщает оконной системе, что окно должно оставаться поверх всех других окон. 
Обратите внимание, что в некоторых оконных менеджерах на `X11` вам также необходимо передать `Qt::X11BypassWindowManagerHint`, чтобы этот флаг работал правильно.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    widget.setWindowFlags(widget.windowFlags() | QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```